# Why are represenations of differential form unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, differential

In Bott&Tu's differential forms in algebraic topology he defines.

> Let $\Omega^*$ be the algebra over $\Bbb R$ generated by $dx_1, \ldots, dx_n$ with the relations 
>       $$
> \begin{cases}
> (dx_i)^2 & = 0 \\ 
> dx_i dx_j &= -dx_j dx_i, \,  i \not= j . 
> \end{cases} $$

And define the differential form as elements of

> $$ \Omega^*(\Bbb R^n) = C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)  \otimes _{\Bbb R} \Omega^*.$$

Then the authors claim

> If $w$ is such a form $w$ can be uniquely written as $\sum f_Id_I$. for some increasing index $I$.

Why **unique?** I see that $d_I$ forms a basis in $\Omega^*$ itself. How does one prove this? I am curious also **what is the general approach in proving some sets forms a basis when given relations**?

---

My thoughts:

Relation in tensor products always seem confusing.  My final thought would be work with decomposition. (= is congruence here)

$$ C^\infty(\Bbb R^n) \otimes \Omega^* = C^\infty(\Bbb R^n) \otimes_{\Bbb R} \bigoplus_I \Bbb R_I = \bigoplus_{I} C^{\infty} \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb R_I = \bigoplus_I C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)_I $$

Comment: Why aren't you happy with your "my thoughts" part ?

Comment: I am unsure if this is how people usually argue...

Comment: If you know that the $d_I$ form a basis, since tensor product distributes over direct sums, your argument is correct